# Is there a maximum amount of energy that can be attached to one Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon

I bought the Mewtwo EX tin and he has an ability called "Shatter Shot".

> This attack does 30 damage multiplied by the amount of "psychic" energy you have on this Pokémon.

I have a bunch of Psychic type energy. Is there a maximum amount of energy you can have on one Pokémon?

Comment: Crazy guess, 59 energy cards.

Answer (score 14):

**There is no limit.**

Each turn you can only attach one energy to one of your Pokémon (either a benched or active Pokémon), and there is no rule limiting the total energy.

The downside of lots of energy on one Pokémon is that if your Mewtwo gets knocked out, all attached energy is put into the discard pile.

Answer (score 5):

The maximum, is the amount you have available in your deck.